# How to display only the year and month with datetime2?

Tags: datetime2

With the `\DTMdisplaydate{yyyy}{mm}{dd}{w}` provided in `datetime2`, one can easily display a specific date. However, one cannot use it directly to display only the year and month, since the third argument cannot left empty. How should one display a time like `2022-01`? (Here the option `useregional` is enabled, so the date should be displayed as a text string in the selected language)

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}

\DTMdate{2022-01-01}

\DTMdisplaydate{2022}{01}{01}{-1}

% \DTMdisplaydate{2022}{01}{}{-1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf), it seems that the predefined format does not support your requirement. You need to set the style yourself. **10.7 Defining a New Date Format** in the document may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a boolean variable `showdayofmonth` that can be set to false for each language used.

```
\DTMdefboolkey{french}{showdayofmonth}[false]{} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\DTMdefboolkey{german}{showdayofmonth}[false]{} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
\DTMdefboolkey{en-GB}{showdayofmonth}[false]{}  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german,french,british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
    \section{Default display}
            
    \selectlanguage{british}
    
    \DTMdate{2022-02-03}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
            
    \DTMdate{2022-02-03}
    
    \bigskip    
    
    \selectlanguage{german}
    
    \DTMdate{2022-02-03}
    
    \bigskip 
    
    \section{Suppress the display of the day}
    
    \DTMdefboolkey{french}{showdayofmonth}[false]{} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \DTMdefboolkey{german}{showdayofmonth}[false]{} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
    \DTMdefboolkey{en-GB}{showdayofmonth}[false]{}  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \selectlanguage{british}
    
    \DTMdate{2022-02-03}    
    
    \bigskip
    
    \selectlanguage{french}
    
    \DTMdate{2022-02-03}
    
    \bigskip    
    
    \selectlanguage{german}
    
    \DTMdate{2022-02-03}
    
\end{document}
```